# Unable to solve Android target error in Meteor add-platform android

Tags: javascript, java, android, meteor

I using a Macbook Pro M1 and decided to do start developing mobile app using Meteorjs framework, since I've used the framework for web development. I've followed a tutorial online on how to get that going but currently facing a problem:

```
Status of the individual requirements:        
✓ Java JDK                                    
✓ Android SDK                                 
✗ Android target: Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
                at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
                at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
                at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
                at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
                at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
                at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
                ... 5 more
✓ Gradle
```

It seems that there's only one requirement that failed, and I've searched for the solution but couldn't find anything that resembles a similar problem that I'm facing. Hoping for you to help point me to the right direction.

I have installed the Android Studio, uninstalled and reinstalled the Android SDK Build-Tools 32, Android SDK Command-line Tools, Android SDK Platform-Tools, and Android Emulator.

Currently, my ~/.bashrc file setup is like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
```

...and my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASS_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib
```

and I've got Gradle working just fine. Tested building a generic Android app using one of the samples in Android Studio. The build was successful.

But I can't get the `meteor add-platform android` to pass the checks. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

This problem was solved by installing JDK8.

Source for Macbook Pro M1: https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-8-lts&os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk

Comment: This is still a working solution in Cordova 11, in my case JDK 1.8.0 worked instead of JDK 11.